# Run virtualmin on subdomain

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualmin, webmin

I have a Centos 7 server that I just installed virtualmin. For the purposes of this question srv1.domain.com will be the hostname of my server. What I am trying to figure out is how to configure Apache so that going to https://srv1.mydomain.com will pass the request to port **10000** without actually showing ***:1000** in the URL.

I know this is fairly simple, but I'm not super great with Apache configurations. My Virtualmin version is 4.18 and my Apache version is Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS).

Comment: The technical term you're looking for is to configure Apache as a Reverse Proxy to virtualmin, the relevant Apache directive is [ProxyPass](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass)

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup reverse proxy with virtualhost in apache and how to do it can be found here in the step by step guide from Webmin below:

[Webmin In A Virtual Host Via A Proxy](http://www.webmin.com/apache.html)